# Having trouble with texturing through vertex groups

Tags: texturing, uv, vertices, texture-painting, vertex-groups

So I'm sure there are tons of better ways to accomplish what I'm trying to do but at the moment because I'm using a PBR texture with color run through a ColorRamp node, I've been trying to denote a few specific areas to be the spots on a dog model and the dog's nose. [image]

The issue I'm running into is that even though the weight painting of the vertex group has a pretty smooth gradient, there is of course, a sharp line dividing the different parts of the texture. [image]

Is there a way to smooth out the difference between the two textures on the dog's body so a more natural looking texture can exist on the dog. I played around with texture painting but it seemed to apply a change to the entire texture PNG rather than a specific part of the mesh if trying it as a material and I couldn't find a way to do the method of more direct color through the ColorRamp, instead it applied what appeared to be an opacity change to the image. I assume texture painting will be the solution but I can't seem to find the solution for this method wherein I am not doing procedural texturing but rather, using a PBR texture.

Blend File Here: https://gofile.io/d/rYlOqw

Comment: I don't think you can use vertex groups to paint. You failed to Texture Paint because the UVs are too big as you can see in the UV Editor, therefore when you're painting on the eye the painting also appears somewhere else. You need to reduce the UV size in the UV Editor. You can also use Vertex Paint as explained by Zophiekat
.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use vertex colors instead of vertex group to achieve this.
assigning materials to faces only work in a 1 or 0 way, this means you cant have 2 materials blend through each other (unless you have an addon like Blendit)

to do this smooth blend you can use vertex colors, just add one in and edit it as if it was weight painting but you do vertex paint instead
[image]
[image]

then use a vertex color node and a mix rgb node, plug the vertex color node into the mix rgb factor to blend between 2 color inputs
[image]

Comment: For the method I have been using, this was the perfect solution!! Thank you so much! I'd only add, if anyone else has this problem, to duplicate the base color nude being used for the texture and run that node through a ColorRamp with the colors you'd like to use and plug that into the other color input as you did for the first one if you'd like it to maintain the texture you are working with.